# Browser scrollbar doesn't work sometimes when using slimscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web, slimscroll

I am using [jquery.slimscroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll)  to replace browser's native scrollbar.

I found sometimes using it causes browser's native scrollbar not responsive to mouse scroll.

One such case:
used along with jqueryui sortable on a element.
Somehow, after rerendering the element, the browser scrollbar stop working.
I can consistently reproduce this in every browser, and I write a jsfiddle to reproduce it:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE8HK/3/)

```
function rerender(){
$("#wrapper").html($("#content").html());
$("#container").sortable({axis:"y",stop:function(){
    rerender();
}});
$("#container").slimScroll(
    {railVisible:true, height:"70px",start:"bottom"});
};

rerender();
```

It happens in other occasions, so this issue may not be related to jqueryui sortable.

Does anyone see similar problems, and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in a way slimScroll handle wheel event - it's attached to window element, so when you recreate your wrapper html, you removes previous scrollable element, but mouse wheel handler remains and prevents window from scrolling. So, in theory you have to destroy custom scrollbar before updating wrapper html, then reinit scrollbar. But in practice slimScroll does not have destroy method.

There is a lot of other scrollbar plugins you can try: [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/), [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), [Malihu Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and others... You can compare their functionality [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing)